# Is kinetic energy of a system conserved during bomb explosion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, explosions

Conservation of momentum is a very obvious thing, but I can't figure out if kinetic energy would be conserved or not. You can think in two ways:

1. Initial kinetic energy is zero and final kinetic energy is some constant and so kinetic energy is not conserved
2. Just after explosion is kinetic energy (at this instant) equal to kinetic energy after a while? If yes then kinetic energy is conserved just after explosion to anytime and if no then why?

Is total energy of the system conserved that is chemical energy=kinetic energy of the system?

For clarity, the explosion occurs in empty space.

Comment: Why do you think kinetic energy would be conserved?

Comment: Lets suppose that explosion occurs at t=0 ,now at t>0(just after explosion)chemical energy is converted to kinetic energy .Now the components move with some velocity and what I'm assuming is that kinetic energy is constant then after (no forces act after explosion ),so kinetic energy remains same . But in a book I follow it is given that kinetic energy increases after explosion then definitely kinetic energy is not conserved.If the book is right ,then why kinetic energy increases?

Comment: The chemical reaction would surely impart a force on the components for some finite time after $t=0$, chemical reactions are not instantaneous processes.

Comment: You want readers to shadow-box with a book they are not told about, with page and formula numbers?

Comment: I didn't mention the book name because I thought that many would not know about it.well! the book is cengage (for jee advanced) mechanics part 2(page1.12 'note').The note says that kinetic energy of broken parts will increase due to internal energy provided due to explosion.

Comment: Sorry about that, I couldn't proper explanation and this question is a little different also

Answer (score 1):

Imagine yourself in a reference frame where the exploding object is stationary. Before the explosion, $KE_{init}=0$. After the explosion, the fragments are all moving, so $KE_{fin} \neq 0$.

In this scenario, the kinetic energy of the projectiles came from stored (chemical) potential energy of the exploding object (or if you wish you may imagine some other method of storing energy, such as a bunch of compressed springs the suddenly release).

Comment: Yes K.E is non zero ,let it be P.Is P constant?...According to my book it isn't ,so what increases the kinetic energy if my book is right?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. If you are asking about momentum, then we may state that before the explosion, $\vec{p}_{init}=\vec{0}$. After the explosion you have multiple particles moving in different directions who all have their own individual momentum. However, by momentum conservation, the total momentum of all the particles must still be $\vec{p}_{fin,total}=\vec{p}_{fin,1}+\vec{p}_{fin,2}+\vec{p}_{fin,3}+...=\vec{0}$.